# Int Initialization Error during compilation

Tags: java, compiler-errors, initialization

I'm a student working on a simple program (TestLuck) that utilizes an abstract data type "ArrayIntLog". It's supposed to generate a user determined amount of logs and use the "compare()" method to check how many log entries are looped through before a match is found. I'm getting this error:

> TestLuck.java:27: error: variable totalRuns might not have been
>   initialized
>            totalRuns += currentRun; 
>            ^

How am I initializing these variables wrong? Does it have something to do with that fact that I'm using them inside the for loop?

```
public class TestLuck{
   public static void main (String [] args){

      Random rand = new Random();
      int n = rand.nextInt(100); // gives a random integer between 0 and 99.
      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
      double average = 0;
      int totalRuns, currentRun, upperLimit = 0;

      System.out.println("Enter the upper limit of the random integer range: ");
      ArrayIntLog arr = new ArrayIntLog(kbd.nextInt());
      System.out.println("Enter the number of times to run the test: ");
      int numTests = kbd.nextInt();

      for(int j=0; j<=numTests; j++){
         for(int i=0; i<arr.getLength(); i++){  //loops through ArrayIntLog and loads random values
            n = rand.nextInt(100);
            arr.insert(n);  //insert a new random value into ArrayIntLog
            if(arr.contains(n)){
               currentRun = i+1;
               i = arr.getLength();
            }
         }    
         totalRuns += currentRun; 
         currentRun = 0;          
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: variable totalRuns might not have been initialized totalRuns += currentRun;

I really think this says it all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, local variables always need to be initialized before they are used.  Here, you are not initializing `totalRuns` (only `upperLimit` is initialized here).

```
int totalRuns, currentRun, upperLimit = 0;
```

Give it (and `currentRun`) an explicit value.

```
int totalRuns = 0, currentRun = 0, upperLimit = 0;
```

This behavior is specified by the JLS, Section 4.12.5:

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
>   before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
>   (§15.26)...

Comment: and currentRun should be initialised as well

Answer (score 1):

```
int totalRun, currentRun, upperLimit = 0;
```

local variables need to be initialized before being used.

Example:

```
int totalRun=0, currentRun=0, upperLimit = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare

```
int totalRuns, currentRun, upperLimit = 0;
```

but don't initialize `totalRuns`. So

```
totalRuns += currentRun;
```

doesn't have a value to add to. Initialize it to a default value, for example `0` (same for others)

```
int totalRuns = 0;
```